# Changing checked button in buttongroup

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using C++ with QT. I have pushbuttons in buttongroup. When I set to all buttons autoExclusive property (), I have following effect. Using arrows I can switch which button in the group is checked. if AutoExclusive is false. I can't switch between buttons.

I want to understand why?

I also want to understand this: is there a way to change just focus  of the buttons with the arrows (not the checked button).

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons belonging to the same group are supposed to be mutually exclusive (this is the aim of grouping them, in the first place). In Qt **you can navigate the buttons using the arrow keys, if they all belong to the same group** (i.e. are in a QButtonGroup with the `exclusive` property set, or on the same widget and each of them has the `autoExclusive` property set). Whenever you set to false the `autoExclusive` property for a button, you're basically excluding it from the group (you can think of it as if it had a group all for itself), so you can no more reach it using the arrow keys.

As for your second question: no, you can't. A user is supposed to reach a button group using the Tab key, then **navigate inside the group** to choose (check) an option using the arrow keys, and move the focus away using the Tab key, when done.